# When immune to a condition, do you still gain the condition?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, conditions, immunities

I was wondering if a creature who is immune to a condition, such as fatigue for a Horizon Walker with Terrain Dominance Desert, actually gains the fatigued condition, but does not take the listed penalties for it.

This seems to be a very important distinction for a Barbarian, in the case of fatigue and rage.  Also for shaken or frightened, as their effects can stack to Panicked if they are not immune to that also.

[This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/45853/34936) seems to say that you do gain the condition.  However, [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/74298/34936) suggests that immunity to fatigue lets a barbarian enter and leave rage without worrying about that.  The second answer is to a 3.5 question, so it could be something that changed between the two.

Comment: Don't forget to mark a satisfying answer so this question can be completed.

Comment: From my understanding, i am supposed to wait a day or two before marking an answer, so i was waiting until today to mark an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.**

> A creature with immunities takes no damage from listed sources. Immunities can also apply to afflictions, conditions, spells (based on school, level, or save type), and other effects. A creature that is immune does not suffer from these effects, or any secondary effects that are triggered due to an immune effect.

Where it says that *does not suffer from these effects* it means that the effect is not applied at all. "Effects" in that case is the list of all conditions that the creature is immune to, not their specific rules or side-effects.

**A Barbarian with Immunity to Fatigue condition can end and restart Rage on the same round.**

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that 'does not suffer from these effects' definitively means they don't get it at all (suffering effects to me means the actual penalties), but I agree that the following line negates the concerns of that caveat.

Comment: Also note, because exiting and entering a rage are 'Free Actions' it puts the decision of if its possible *up to the DM*. I'd go in on a bet that any DM with even moderate experience would say you can't perform those 2 Free Actions in the same round. You might wiggle in ending at the end of a turn and starting before actions the next turn, but even that is questionable. Expect to be slammed with Dominate in that window, though.

Comment: @Ifuaso "suffering" doesn't imply negative penalties, exactly. You can also be immune to a positive effect like Morale Bonuses or something and you will not "suffer" them. Suffering means being afflicted/affected by the condition in this case. If you want my post to make more sense, look at it like this: remove "other effects" after "spells", and change "does not suffer from these effects" to "does not suffer from these conditions/mechanics", that's the least ambiguous interpretation.

Comment: Valid, and it's not that I didn't understand what you were thinking, just that the rule itself chose its words poorly.

Comment: The word "effect" is the culprit, but I can't think of a better one for what they were going for.